# MongoDB How to Find out the records which are not in between the date range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections like below,

**user Collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af2e946aa546125b5de85cc"),
    "name" : "Sudhin",
    "email" : "abc@abc.com",
    "roles" : [ 
        "Reader", 
        "Instructor"
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-09T12:27:50.651Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-16T09:22:07.280Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af2f3a6efb83031faaa3d82"),
    "name" : "Rahul",
    "email" : "abcd@abc.com",
    "roles" : [ 
        "Reader", 
        "Instructor"
    ]
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-09T13:12:06.518Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-16T09:22:07.281Z")
}
```

**schedulers Collections**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afd763b8fad29597e1b85ed"),
    "title" : "ILT Course",
    "type" : "Course",
    "ilt" : {
        "instructorId" : ObjectId("5af2e946aa546125b5de85cc"),
        "type" : "ILT-Offline",
        "instructorName" : "Sudhin",
        "place" : "*******",
        "description" : "******"
    },
    "startDate" : ISODate("2018-05-10T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2018-05-15T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-17T12:31:55.574Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-17T12:31:55.575Z")
}
```

In the scheduler collection "ilt.instructorId" is the referenceId for user.

Scheduler collection is having all the details of a particular user schedule.

startDate is the starting date and time of a particular schedule.
endDate is the ending date and time of a particular schedule.

When I pass startDate to endDate(2018-05-05 00:00 -  2018-05-10 00:00), I want to fetch all the users with role instructor and who do not have any scheduled courses in between those dates.

Eg: If I'm passing  2018-05-05 00:00 -  2018-05-10 00:00 it should return
the below document

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af2f3a6efb83031faaa3d82"),
        "name" : "Rahul",
        "email" : "abcd@abc.com",
        "roles" : [ 
            "Reader", 
            "Instructor"
        ]
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-09T13:12:06.518Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-16T09:22:07.281Z")
    }
```

I have tried the below query

```
UserModel.query().aggregate([

    { $match: { roles: { $in: ['Instructor'] } } },

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "schedulers",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "ilt.instructorId",
            as: "schedule"
        }

    },

    {
        $match: {
            "schedule.type": "Course",
            $and: [

                { 'schedule.endDate': { $not: { $lte: new Date("2018-05-12T12:00:00.000Z") } }},
                { 'schedule.startDate': { $not: { $gte: new Date("2018-05-06T11:00:00.000Z") } }},
            ]
        }
    },


    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            empId: 1,
            startDateTime: "$schedule.startDate",
            endDateTime: "$schedule.endDate",
    }
}])
```

Comment: Post here what you have tried so far

Comment: Sure, i have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below query its help you:

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([

    { $match: { roles: { $in: ['Instructor'] } } },

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "schedulers",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "ilt.instructorId",
            as: "schedule"
        }

    }, 
    {
        $match: {
            "schedule.type": "Course",
            $or: [
               { 'schedule.startDate': {  $lt: new Date("2018-05-08T11:00:00.000Z")  }},
                { 'schedule.endDate': {  $gt: new Date("2018-05-14T12:00:00.000Z") }},

            ]
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$schedule',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },


    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            empId: 1,
            schedule:'$schedule',
            startDateTime: "$schedule.startDate",
            endDateTime: "$schedule.endDate",
    }
}])
```